# highcharts.js change color of the lines in the background

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I have a basic bar chart. I want to change the color of the lines in the background. Is there any way to do that? I looked over their API and the internet. Seem like I can only change the background color

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/er6jqq84/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'          
        },
        colors: ['#00A7E5'],
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun', 'Mon']},
        yAxis: {
            title: {text: ''},
            tickInterval: 10

            },
        series: [{
            name: 'TOTAL APPTS.',
            data: [25, 30, 35, 27, 33, 20, 10]
        }],
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
         credits: {
            enabled: false
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the following line in the yAxis options after tick interval.

```
gridLineColor: 'color'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gridLineColor: '#ed7d31',
lineColor: '#F3F5F6',
minorGridLineColor: '#ed7d31',
tickColor: '#F3F5F6',
plotLines: [{
    color: '#ed7d31'
}],
```